# How to create a detailed route search feature like google map for Google map v2 android development

Tags: java, android, xml, eclipse

How do I add a searching routing feature from start point to end point like original google map application? But I can't get any example codes for leverage

Comment: That's a very broad topic. Any info on what you've already tried, what you've researched, or more information on the specifics of your problem, that prevents you from using the features of Google Maps itself?

Comment: BTW, what have you tried? Have you done any homework by yourself?

Comment: I've only started this project for 1 month ago, so I have just added a simple google map v2 , taught in the Google Developer, I can get the current location . Last task of my project is the routing search feature , I have no clue on how to start this routing